# Overshoot and rise time for high order system

Tags: control-theory

For second order systems it is easy to determine overshoot and rise time, as well as peak time and setting time. How to determine these specifications for systems larger than two?. Each pole has its own damping ratio and natural frequency, how can I somehow get the system response specifications as a function of the natural frequency and damping ratio of each pole?

Comment: What kind of systems are you considering, only systems that can be written as a [proper transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_transfer_function)? What about a delay? It can also be noted that even the overshoot and rise- and settling time of a proper second order transfer functions are not fully described by only its damping ratio and natural frequency. For example the following two transfer function have the same poles but quite different step responses $$G_1(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+0.1\,s+1},\quad G_2(s)=\frac{1-3\,s}{s^2+0.1\,s+1}.$$

Comment: I am considering the simplest system without zeros and no delay. The traditional formulations presented in the control books for specification calculation are for without zeros systems. Considering a third-order system without zeros, how could you calculate the resulting overshoot? Each pole has a natural frequency and damping ratio, as these parameters contribute to, for example, system overshoot?

Comment: No. You can't. The best thing you can do it is to approximate it as a second order system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer